# Changing values at specific indices - R

Tags: r

I have two vectors a & b.

`a <- c(1,0,1,0,0,0,1)`

`b <- c(.2,.9,.3,.9,.8,.78,.3)`

and I want to subtract 1 from all values in b that correspond to indices for 1 in a. I can extract the indices of all values that are 1 in a by doing `which(a == 1)`. I tried doing something like `b <- 1 - b[which(a == 1)]` but this didn't work. Is there some way to do this without using a for loop?

Answer (score 4):

We can convert the binary vector 'a' to logical by double negation (`!!` - converts 1 to TRUE and 0 to FALSE) or by just wrapping with `as.logical` or as in the OP's code (`a==1`).  This will subset the values in 'b' that corresponds to TRUE/1 in 'a'.  Subtract 1 from those values and assign the output back to those values in 'b'

```
b[a==1] <- 1 - b[a==1]
```

Or we can use `ifelse`

```
ifelse(a==1, 1-b, b)
```

---

In the OP's code, wrapping with `which` is not needed and also assigning to 'b' with a subset of elements of 'b' replaces the original vector 'b' with the subset 'b'

Answer (score 4):

Your `a` vector is 0's and 1's. If you want to subtract 1 from `b` whenever `a` is 1, and do nothing (aka *subtract 0*) from `b` whenever `a` is 0, then this is just subtraction:

```
b - a
```

---

If your `a` vector has values other than 0 or 1, then you'll need a *slightly* more complicated, more general method as in @akrun's answer.

Another "more complex" variant would use the implicit meaning of `TRUE` as 1 and `FALSE` as 0 to do

```
b - (a == 1)
```

---

Upon re-reading, you might need to clarify what you want. Your text says *subtract 1 from all values in b*, which implies `b - (1 or 0)`. However, you code attempt is `1 - b`, subtracting *b from 1* not *1 from b*, in which case akrun's answer is perfect and mine would need some adjustments.